# How to move a file/window from one desktop to another desktop?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, drag-and-drop

I've updated the system to Ubuntu 11.10 and set Gnome Shell as default GUI. Now I cannot move files from one desktop to another.

Let me illustrate this. I used to have Thunderbird maximized on desktop 1. When I create a new email and want to add attachments to it, I went to another desktop (desktop 2 or 3), grabbed the file from it, moved it to the left side of screen which made the screen rotate to desktop 1, and then just dropped the file into an email message.

Example no.2. The same procedure was when I wanted to move an open screen of some app from one desktop to another.

With this new Gnome Shell, desktops do not rotate left and right, but up and down. If I grab a file on one desktop and move it to the top/bottom, the screen does not rotate at all. Of course, the same is with the left/right side.

So, how can I made Gnome Shell rotate desktops when I touch one side of the screen (either top/bottom or left/right)? Has this been implemented at all?

PS. I know that I can move screens via desktop shortcuts. However, they are useless when I want to move files.

**EDIT**

I found a way to move files. Grab it, move to upper left corner, navigate to the right desktop, touch some windows on that desktop to get focus and then drop the file into it.

Comment: I'm not sure about gnome3, but it used to be an option of the corrosponding compiz-plugin. In ccsm you had to chose desktop-wall or expo sth. and select an option for touching an edge of your screen...

Comment: @Simon Gnome3 does not like ccsm as all these options are enabled, but Gnome3 does not respect them.

Comment: @ubuntico: you are using Gnome Shell. I cleared that up in my edit. Gnome 3 != Gnome Shell != Gnome 3. Unity also runs on Gnome 3. Also, please post your edit as an answer.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Thanks. I did not know that :)

Comment: I found a way to move file, but not window. I'll edit the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to move a window from a workspace to the other one is launching to Activities Overview, and dragging the window to the list of workspaces on the right side of Activities Overview.

You can use screen edges for desktop switching with an extension.
Here it is : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/136/desktop-scroller
When you scroll at the right edge of your screen, desktops are switching up and down.

By default, it uses right edge of screen.

Comment: I went to this page, set ON on the left part of the screen, got a message saying if I want to install this... and now what? I touch the right edge with some window and nothing happens.

Comment: And yes, the extension is activated and either side I touch, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you mean "clicking" with the word "touch"?  If so, you have to scroll, not click (or touch)

Comment: Yes, I can scroll now. But how to move a window from one desktop to another?